how do i start a react web with https in localhost
I'm working on a react app where the app needs to open on https://localhost:300 but its opening on http://localhost:3000.
I'm using windows OS and to make the app work i did the following

generated the self signed certificate

added it to the root level of the project

my package json has
"start": "set HTTPS=true && set REACT_APP_GIT_VERSION=$(git rev-parse head) && react-scripts start",
"safeStart": "export HTTPS=true&&SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.pem&&SSL_KEY_FILE=key.pem react-scripts start",

when i try to run the app by using npm start or set HTTPS=true&&npm start the app is up and opening in the broswer but served on http but not on https.

when i try to run the app using the npm safeStart or  set HTTPS=true&&npm safeStart, i'm getting error at SSL saying its not configured.


I'm not sure if i'm missing something or i need to add some additional configs or so.
======================UPDATE====================
I made this work by doing the following,

generated the ssl using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkcert
mapped the start command with reference to the key and file parameter
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=C:/Windows/System32/cert.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=C:/Windows/System32/cert.key&&react-scripts start",
now give npm start it should start the app on https://localhost:3000


Does this answer your question? create-react-app: how to use https instead of http?

@AndréLehto I did try these, but stills serves on http
